# How to tell the Python IDE (and interpreter) the type of a variable

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I was pleasantly surprised to find out that Eclipse with PyDev is able to guess the type of most variables and helps showing the list of the members. I'm learning Python, and I thought that I should forget about all the advantages of strongly typed languages, but it looks like I was wrong.

I would like to know how far the IDE (or even the Python interpreter) goes. I have a few module level variables defined as in the snippet below, and I would like for the IDE to know their type.

Question 1 about the IDE: Is it possible to declare the type of a variable so that the code completion knows about its members?

Question 2 about Python: Is it possible to declare the type of a variable so that I get a warning if the type is changed during the execution?

For example placing the cursor after the first `c.` on the following snippet and pressing `ctrl+space`, the first suggestion is `val`. Yay!

Python variables are dynamic, their type can change, and this trick doesn't work on the second `c.` because there is no way for Eclipse to know that the `c` defined at module level and used in `func2` is going to be defined in `func1`.

```
c = None

class MyClass:
    val = 0

def func1():
    c = MyClass()
    print c. # Eclipse knows that val is a member of c 

def func2():
    print c. # Eclipse doesn't know that val is a member of c
```

Comment: As of now, the `c = None` line is doing absolutely nothing. You're defining `c` in the global scope, but none of your code is in the global scope. The `c`'s in `func1` and `func2` are both different from the `c` you define up there and different from each other. Perhaps your IDE isn't recognizing `val` as a member of `c`, because `c` has not yet been defined in that scope and thus **has** no members, class or even value

Comment: @Josh: I forgot the `global c` inside the two functions, which itself improves the quality of the guessing. One comment and two answers all very helpful, but the `assert isinstance()` is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def something(c):
    #eclipse does not know what c is
    assert isinstance(c,MyClass)
    #now eclipse knows that c is an instance of MyClass
    c. #autocomplete
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the assert isinstance() does work, PyDev 2.8 added a way of adding that information without the assert, just through documenting your code properly (using sphinx or epydoc docstrings).

See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html for details on how to document the code properly for it to accept the type declarations.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `decorators` your IDE will probably realize what you're doing:

```
@accepts(MyClass)   #Let python and the interpreter know
def foo(bar):       #You're only accepting MyClass isntances
    bar.            #Should autocomplete
```

Comment: please provide more details.  as your example results in a syntax error (at least in python 2.6)